# Marker changes its position while zoom in or out in google map v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using Google map V2 to put several markers on map. i am using default marker with different color, my problem is that  when i perform zoom in or out operation marker changes its position.

[image: Before zoom]

[image: After Zoom in]

I have searched a lot but didn't get any solution.

to add marker i am using following code

```
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(serverResponse.get(i).getLat(), serverResponse.get(i).getLon())).title(data).snippet(data2));
```

Comment: Try to set `.flat(true)` in `Marker Options`

Comment: This will not work in my case because .flat(true) is use to rotate the marker if we rotate our map, and i want to make my marker not to move when i perform zoom in or out

Comment: Is this a device specific issue? What's your device density?

Comment: This is not a device specific issue it happens on different other devices having different resolution

Answer (score 6):

You have forgotten to call to the method

> .anchor(float a, float b)

when you are adding  your maker.
Please try this:

```
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(serverResponse.get(i).getLat(), serverResponse.get(i).getLon())).title(data).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f).snippet(data2));
```

Comment: It's work for thank you.